# How to unzip a .gz string in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, gzip, zlib

I am downloading a `.csv.gz` file from a remote server, and I have the contents of this file stored as a string. Here is a small sample of what I see when I `console.log` it:

```
�}�v������)��t�Y�j�8p0�eCR��

l��1�=���6������~̵r�����0c7�7L���������U:���0�����g��
```

How can I unzip this in Node.js so that it converts it to the original `.csv` file?

I have tried `zlib.gunzip(Buffer.new(body), callback)`, but then I get an error

> incorrect header check at Gunzip.zlibOnError (zlib.js:152:15)

The file itself is valid, and I can double-click to unzip and open it on my computer.

I create the file using: `zlib.createGzip();` and then `gzip.pipe(writeStream);`

---

**Update**

The (actual) issue was my data was `utf8` encoded so I needed to ensure that it remained either as a Buffer or binary.

Comment: When you mentioned you stored the .csv.gz as a string. How are you encoding that?

Comment: How is `writeStream` defined?

Comment: @Eelke I am just piping it to a normal `fs.createWriteStream` which results in this `.csv.gz` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `fs.createWriteStream` defaults to `utf-8` encoding, you should change that to `binary`, then you'll be able to create a valid buffer that `gunzip` will happily accept.

You could probably accomplish this by changing your code to:

```
gzip.pipe(data => writeStream(data, { encoding: 'binary'})
```

> see https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options

Comment: Thanks. I tried changing it to `binary` but then I'm unable to download and unzip the file natively on my macbook.

Comment: Where is `body` coming from in your example? That's probably a utf-8 encoded string, if you can manage to change the encoding to binary (when the buffer changes to a string) you should be good

Comment: You're right! That's the culprit - hopefully this will work

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: 
I have modified the code so that now you have a ArrayBuffer which gets actually decompressed.

```
  function decompressFile(filename) {
       var decompress = zlib.createUnzip(),
        input = fs.createReadStream(filename);      
        var data = [];
        input.on('data', function(chunk){
            data.push(chunk);               
        }).on('end', function(){
            var buf = Buffer.concat(data);
            zlib.gunzip(buf, function(err, buffer) {
              if (!err) {
                console.log(buffer.toString()+'\n');
              }else{
                console.log(err);
              }
            });
        });
}
decompressFile('TestFileSheet1.csv.gz');
```

This looks straight forward. But I think the problem might be somewhere else in your code Or the http library that you are using. Check whether the response header's content encoding is gzip and then call the zlib.gunzip. I think your http library might already be decompressing the csv file.

Comment: Thanks but I think my scenario is different in that I will already have the contents stored as a string (not a buffer), and don't have a file to read from. How could this be applied using your approach?

Comment: @d-_-b . I have updated my answer. I wasnt able to use any sample http csv. So i am just creating the ArrayBuffer when reading the file.